# Problems running KOTOR I in Virtual Box

Tags: windows, games, windows-xp

My host machine is running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and the virtual box is running Windows xp. I'm trying to run KOTOR 1 through shared files but I keep getting hit with error 5:0000065434. Looking it up it seems this error is caused by Steam.exe being on a different drive than the game and the bandaid solution is to just copy and paste Steam.exe into the games file folder. But since linux doesn't have .exe files (I think, I'm still a little new to this) how can I get this to work?

Comment: Du you  try to run KOTOR 1 in Windows XP in VirtualBox, or directly in Ubuntu and Steam ?

Comment: Inside of VB I found the steam files and tried to run KOTOR.exe

Comment: This is more a Windows question than an Ubuntu one. You have to start windows in VB and run the ,exe file inside there. Windows executable files cannot be run natively in Ubuntu. Please update your question with the EXACT steps you follow.